# How to use the `node` user in an official node docker image on GitLab CI?

Tags: node.js, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

In `Dockerfile`, we can use `USER node` to change to the non-root user. But in `.gitlab-ci.yml`, I don't know how the switch the user and make everything (cache, artifacts, etc) work.

My current solution is using `su node -c <command>`. But maybe there are better ways to do this.

**EDIT**

For example,

```yaml
image: node:14

stages:
  - Init

init:
  stage: Init
  script:
    - su node -c "npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline" # works, but ugly
  cache:
    key: npm
    paths:
      - .npm/
```

Comment: I don't really follow; can you share your `.gitlab-ci.yml` as well?

Comment: @msanford I've edited my question.

Comment: Regardless of any USER settings in the Dockerfile, Gitlab CI jobs are always run as root. There is no way to configure this, so running `su ...` is the only way to get a non-root user inside your CI job.